# Modeling time spent on different websites

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, encoding

Apologies in advance for the poor title. I didn't know exactly how to phrase what I want in a succinct manner so hopefully I can elaborate a bit more.

I have a dataset where I have customer_id, url_visited, and time_spent. So It looks like this (key is the url, value is time_spent):

| customer_id | url | time_spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | google.com | 20 min |
| 1 | facebook.com | 30 min |
| 2 | napster.com | 5 min. |
| 2 | netscape.com | 6 min |

So let's say I care less about whether or not they visited a site, (i.e `is_google` or `is_netscape`) and more about how long they visited each site (i.e `time_spent_google`, `time_spent_facebook`), what would be the best way to model this?

My idea is to do something like this:

| customer_id | time_spent_napster | time_spent_facebook | time_spent_google |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 min | 30 min | 20 min |
| 2 | 6 min | 0 min | 0 min |

So a couple of questions:

1. Would this be an acceptable way to model this data in most traditional ml models such as RF?
2. If yes, what would be a technique to encode this with high cardinality data?

Any input is welcomed!

Comment: Based on your task you can just do simple data analysis and pivot and/or groupby will get results ... modeling approach is not something that will give anything here and for RF target is not there so how to do best split ... you try unsupervised learning on supervised data (note: modeling is for prediction/model data and not query-value,  because you already have rdbms to do this type of queries).

Comment: I did forget to mention that there is a dependent variable for me to do train/test split on, so I think supervised is the way to go here. I also simplified the data set as there are many other IVs in this data set. I included those 3 because I wasn't sure how to feature engineer those specifically.

Comment: Without an imaginary dataset is impossible to think of a method of encoding, formulate the problem, provide sample of the data and not only a subset of the features (here is no clear option on how to encode and what you predict). Just keep them as categorical this columns and fit into NN (this features you create will not bring any value).